# AppBarLayout child doesn't collapse when scrolling

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout

I have a `AppBarLayout` which contains an horizontal `RecyclerView` among its children.
The sibling of the `AppBarLayout` is a `ViewPager` (which contains a vertical `RecyclerView`).

Here is the XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.search.SearchResultFragment">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="@dimen/d2"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_image_view"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_backarrow_gray"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/query_terms_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_image_view"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_gray"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/related_terms_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/search_term_bg"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d8"
        android:background="@color/tab_and_nav_bar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I already have another UI with `AppBarLayout` which is able to respond to scroll successfully with a `Toolbar` . The code is pretty much the same, but in this case something is wrong because the `RecyclerView` is not collapsing / hiding.

Comment: What is your problem in detail?

Comment: It just does not response to scrolling gesture. It should hide the recycler view but nothing happen.

Comment: I believe the "scrollable" (hidable) views must be at the top. Does it work if you move the RecyclerView *before* the LinearLayout ?

Comment: I mean that the content of AppBarLayout should be 1. RecyclerView (with scrollFlags); 2 LinearLayout; 3. TabLayout . Does it work this way?

Comment: Hey I am trying right now. I will reply to your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Big thanks to @m vai for the tips**

I solved this problem customising the behaviour of the `AppBarLayout`
Here is the code:

```
private void setAppBarLayoutBehaviour() {
    AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior() {

        @Override
        public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
            // Trigger the following events if it is a vertical scrolling
            return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
            super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

            // If I slowly reach the top, without fling, show the RecyclerView
            int[] firstVisiblePositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) ((RecyclerView) target).getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPositions(null);
            for (int position : firstVisiblePositions) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    showRelatedTerms();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNestedFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
            if (velocityY > 500) {
                // Hide the RecyclerView
            } else if (velocityY < -500) {
                // Show the recyclerView
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(behavior);
}
```

And I didn't apply any `scrollFlags` in the XML.

Answer (score 4):

- `AppBarLayout` is just a vertical `LinearLayout`, so order counts;
- what makes child *react to scroll gestures* is actually defining the `scroll` flags through the `android:layout_scrollFlags` attribute.

From the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL) for that flag, we can read that

> The view will be scroll in direct relation to scroll events. This flag
>   needs to be set for any of the other flags to take effect. If any
>   sibling views before this one do not have this flag, then this value
>   has no effect.

That means that your flag is ignored because the other childs do not have any flags. I believe the reason behind this is that we want only the *top* views to be hidden - bottom views can't disappear if there's still something above.

So the solution in this case (which you might not like) is to, either:

- move that view to the top, so it will be the only view exiting;
- give all views the `scroll` flag. They'll react together to scroll gestures, which might not be what you want.

  ```
  <AppBarLayout>
      <RecyclerView ...
          android:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

      <LinearLayout ... >
      <TabLayout ... >
  </AppBarLayout>
  ```

Comment: It almost works thanks :) I moved the ```RecyclerView``` to the top. I left the other children without any ```scrollFlags```. The result is as expected: the ```RecylerView``` scrolls out and the others are kept visible. The only thing is that by design the ```RecyclerView``` should stay between the ```LinearLayout``` and the ```TabLayout``` :( any idea?

Comment: Maybe make the LinearLayout scroll too?

Comment: Yes it will work for sure but the point is: what if I want a layout like this? I mean a top linear layout, a recycler view and a tab layout, and I need only the recycler view to react to the scroll events? I guess this approach doesnt allow me to create this kind of layout. What you think?

Comment: Then you can't do it using AppBarLayout. The solution that comes to mind is defining a custom `Behavior` for that RecyclerView and override `onNestedScroll()`. There, when user is scrolling down you make the RV invisible (`setVisibility(View.GONE)`); when scrolling up, you make it visible again (`setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`). Try searching for a "custom behavior" example if you really need so.

Comment: Thanks man. I customised the behaviour, but I did it in another way :)

Comment: "AppBarLayout is just a vertical LinearLayout, so order counts;". This helped me, thanks!