# CoordinatorLayout not scrolling properly

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to implement a Main Activity consisting of an appbar and a staggered grid of "articles"

My appbar doesn't have any menu buttons, only an imageView that contains the app's brand.

I implemented a coordinator layout because I want to achieve the following behavior when I scroll the grid:

- The appbar, which is 112dp high, should collapse until it reaches the height described in the minHeight attribute. The recyclerview elements should pass below it. The image should shrink about 20% to make the visual effect more impactful.

For some reason, when I scroll the recyclerview, the appbar remains in its original position and doesn't collapse.

This is my xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?colorPrimary">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_toolbar_side_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_toolbar_side_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:paddingTop="116dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_side_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_side_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="28dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can you help me, please?

P.S.: Is there any online resource that teaches you how to implement the material design scrolling techniques? Especially the last one in the following link:

http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog#scrolling-techniques-scrolling

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112339/appbarlayout-child-doesnt-collapse-when-scrolling

Comment: I tracked the issue but it doesn't solve my specific problem. If someone knows another possible cause, please let me know

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try to make Parent layout ScrollView Behaviour

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
```